# Keep regenerating different random numbers in Android

Tags: java, android, loops, random

I am making an app for Android, and I need a number, that will keep changing randomly every time I call it.

But, if I do this:

```
Random r = new Random(); // makes random r
public int rndNum = r.nextInt(1000) + 7;
```

and use `rndNum` a few times, it remains the same randomly generated number every time.

Is there a way to keep regenerating the random number?

Comment: Using `Random` doesnt mean that you always will get different number, that can be same number too. If you want alwasy a `unique one` use [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: no, I keep pressing the button that generates the number and even after 10 times it's still the same number.

Comment: Please show the whole method that is supposed to generate the number and how the button calls that.

Comment: no need to, found the solution, in @Jaydeep Gadhia 's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try SecureRandom class : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Initialization in expensive but you can initialize SecureRandom once at startup of your application and then keep using it.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of contextual code posted, I cannot verify this,but I am pretty sure OP is doing something similar to this:

```
public static class SomeObject {
    Random r = new Random(); // makes random r
    public int rndNum = r.nextInt(1000) + 7; 

    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return this.rndNum;
    }
}

public static SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JButton j = new JButton();
    ...
    j.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(obj.getRandomNumber());
        }
    });
}
```

This basically means that a new random number is NOT generated every time the button is pressed. The random number generated once and saved as `rndNum`. Thus every time the button is pressed, the same number will be returned.

The accepted answer will solve this, but I feels wasteful to keep track of every generated random number.

The way to solve this is to change the `getRandomNumber` method to generate a random number every time the method is called:

```
public int getRandomNumber() {
    return new Random().nextInt(1000) + 7; 
}
```

Comment: You are right. @ely-shaffir generates one random number in `rndNum` variable and always reads this variable value without refreshing it's value. Ely have to generate new random number into `rndNum` every time he/she presses a button.